# Problema con PHP y MySQL al realizar gráfico en HighChart

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de realizar un gráfico dinámico con `Highchart` que se actualiza cada segundo, sin refrescar la página. Para obtener los datos de `MySql` estoy usando `PHP`, el problema es que cuando se realiza la consulta  en `PHP` `(select * from temperatura ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1)` con el cual obtengo el último registro de la tabla temperatura, se queda guardado y por más que añada un nuevo registro en la tabla temperatura, cuando se refresca el gráfico, el valor consultado primera vez por `PHP` es el que sigue permaneciendo el gráfico, y no el del último `INSERT`

Este es en el fragmento donde ingresos nuevos valores en el gráfico:

```php
events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];

                if(myTimervar){
                    window.clearInterval(myTimervar);
                }
                myTimervar = setInterval(function () {

                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = <?php
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "p1") or
                            die("Problemas con la conexión");

                            $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from temperatura ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1") or
                            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));

                            while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
                            echo $reg['grado'];
                            }
                            mysqli_close($conexion);
                            ?>

                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                }, 1000);
            }
        }
```

Este es el código completo:

```php
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px; 
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Gráfico de temperatura que muestra la actualización de datos cada segundo, con la eliminación de datos antiguos.
    </p>
</figure>



<script type="text/javascript">
var myTimervar;
var contador=1;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];

                if(myTimervar){
                    window.clearInterval(myTimervar);
                }
                myTimervar = setInterval(function () {

                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = <?php
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "p1") or
                            die("Problemas con la conexión");

                            $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from temperatura ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1") or
                            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));

                            while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
                            echo $reg['grado'];
                            }
                            mysqli_close($conexion);
                            ?>

                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Temperatura'
    },

    accessibility: {
        announceNewData: {
            enabled: true,
            minAnnounceInterval: 15000,
            announcementFormatter: function (allSeries, newSeries, newPoint) {
                if (newPoint) {
                    return 'New point added. Value: ' + newPoint.y;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Tiempo'
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperatura'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: 0
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Por ejemplo aquí mi último dato registrado de la temperatura es de 24 y por más que añada un nuevo registro en mi base de datos con una temperatura diferente en el último registro, cuando el gráfico se vuelve a actualizar, es como si tomara el mismo valor de la primera consulta realizada en `PHP`.

[image: Por ejemplo aquí mi último dato registrado de la temperatura es de 24 y por más que añada un nuevo registro en mi base de datos con una temperatura diferente en el último registro, cuando el gráfico se vuelve a actualizar, es como si tomara el mismo valor de la primera consulta realizada en PHP.]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que guardas en la columna `fecha`, son la fecha y la hora? ¿Revisaste los datos en la tabla? ¿Borraste la caché del navegador? ¿Si lanzas la consulta en la BD muestra los datos que esperas?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que todo el php -la parte dinámica que necesitas- que está dentro de javascript se convierte en un valor estático al descargar la página; lo puedes comprobar examinando el código js con herramientas de desarrollo del browser, y así observarás que `y` siempre tendrá el mismo valor.

Deberás mover el código php de la consulta a la base de datos a otro archivo php, Ej. en `temperaturas.php`:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "p1") or
                            die("Problemas con la conexión");

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from temperatura ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1") or
                            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
$reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros));
echo $reg['grado'];
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Y en javascript hacer la asignación de `y` con el resultado de un HTTP Request al nuevo php, por ejemplo usando `fetch`y *promesas*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myTimervar = setInterval( async function(){
                                 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                     y = await fetch('http://host/temperaturas.php')
                                                    .then( respuesta => respuesta.text() );
                                 console.log('y=',y);
                                 series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                              }
                            , 1000
                            );
</script>
```

O con la ayuda de tu librería favorita de javascript (jQuery, Axios, Angular, etc.) ya sea con AJAX ó AJAJ, de los cuales hay muchos ejemplos por ahí; donde adicionalmente en el php deberás manejar el formato de datos adecuado XML ó JSON.

Comment: Gracias mi hermano me funcionó :) !!!